# getEntityManager on Symfony 3.0.6

Tags: symfony

From version 3.0.6 they have definitively removed (deleted) the getEntityManager () method and now it's getManager ().

If you are using version 3.0.0 you will have no problems, but with version 3.0.6 or higher Symfony realize that when we do this

```
$em = $ this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
```

In one action you must change it to this

```
$em = $ this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

To work properly.

Is it possible to continue using getEntityManager () in versions 3.0.6 or higher?

Regards

Comment: The method no longer exists, so no, you can't call it any more. I suppose if you're eager to avoid rewriting the calls in your application, you could override the Doctrine service with your own class that implements getEntityManager() and passes calls to it to getManager().

Comment: I think your timeline is way off.  This getEntityManager has been triggering an error for about 4 years now.  I really don't think it worked in S3.0.  Oddly enough, even in the DoctrineBundle master branch the method still exists.  But again triggers an error.  It's possible that whatever code you are using has changed how trigger_error is handled?  In any event, no need to fool with it at all,  Just use $this->get('doctrine.orm.manager')

Answer (score 5):

`getEntityManager()` has been deprecated since Symfony2.1.

Don't use it, use `getManager()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I never did the probeThanks. I never did the test